# Can you identify this book?

Tags: analysis, reference-request, soft-question

I am looking for a very conceptual book on analysis to recommend it to one of my juniors. I have a book in my mind which I once read during my UG days in my college library on one fine morning, a book on Real analysis, in which all I remember is the how limits were defined-

He/She/They explained limits of a function $f(x)$, i.e. to look at formal definition which is

> Ler $f:A\to R$ and $c$ be a limit point of $A$. We say that $\text{lim}_{x\to c}f(x)=L$, provided that, for all $\epsilon >0$, there exist a $\delta>0$ such that whenever $0<|x-c|<\delta$ (and $x\in A$) it follows that $|f(x)-L|\ <\epsilon$

as to imagine your function to be a cannon, and it has to shoot an enemy ($L$) who is in some tower, who can be seen in a window of size $2\epsilon$, i.e. $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, then you can always find an a position to set your cannon within range of $2\delta$ from your initial position of cannon which is considered to be $x$ (or something like that)

I might not be accurate with I have written, but this was the basic idea they used to explain it. I pretty much liked it back then and cannot recall what book was it. Does somebody know about it, someone here must have read it some time. Please let me know if you can recall.

Many Thanks!

Comment: What is a "first year junior?"

Comment: I mean he he is in first year of UG

Comment: Ah, in the states, a "junior" is a third year student.

Comment: Nice explanation. Unfortunately I don't know the book. I edited the title of the question to reflect better what the question is about.

Comment: @IvoTerek Thanks!